# If I had an infinite plate would the voltage increase as I get away from it?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential, voltage

Because the equation for electric potential is V=-Es, if I were to have an infinite plane of charge emitting uniform electric field would this mean that as I get farther away from it my potential will increase since "s" will increase? My teacher had told me this was wrong and the potential will get less as you move away but I dont understand why.

Comment: Depends on the context really, if V continues to become a larger negative number that is technically becoming smaller since negative numbers are smaller as they increase in magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

The statement *Because the equation for electric potential is $V=-Es$* is meaningless as you have not defined $s$.

The equation you should be quoting relates the electric field $E$ to the potential gradient $\frac{dV}{dx}$, $E=-\frac{dV}{dx}$ where $V$ is the potential at a point $x$ away from the charges plate.
Since the electric field is uniform this can be written as $\Delta V = -E\,\Delta x \Rightarrow V(x_{\rm final}) - V(x_{\rm initial})= -E (x_{\rm final} - x_{\rm initial})$.

Suppose that the plate is positively charged so that $E$ is positive.
Moving away from the plate $x_{\rm final}> x_{\rm initial} \Rightarrow V(x_{\rm final}) < V(x_{\rm initial})$, ie the potential decreases as one moves away from the plate.

You can consider this in a slightly different way.
Place a positive charge near a positively charged plate.
Release the positive charge and note that it moves away from the plate to where the potential is lower.

Comment: Hi how did you end up getting V(final)<V(initial)? Since it is uniform this would Ean we do not need to integrate the formula. In this case why can't I sub into V=-E(sfinal-sInital)?

Comment: I used $\Delta V = -E\,\Delta x $ as no integration is necessary.